# Show that if $\dim(V) = \sum_{i = 0}^k \dim(W_i)$, $W_i \leqslant V$, then $V = W_1 \oplus W_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus W_k$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V = W_1 + W_2 + \dots + W_k$. Show that if $\dim(V) = \sum_{i = 0}^k \dim(W_i)$ and $W_i \leqslant V$, then $$V = W_1 \oplus W_2 \oplus \dots \oplus W_k$$

---

I already look for other articles but I do not find them enough clear for me.

I tried this by inducción over $k$, but I'm not sure if the proof is correct:

Let $k = 2$, since
$$V = W_1 + W_2 \longrightarrow dim(V) = dim(W_1 + W_2) = dim(W_1) + dim(W_2) - dim(W_1 \cap W_2) = dim(V) - dim(W_1 \cap W_2)$$
Thus, $W_1 \cap W_2 = \{\bar{0}\}$.

Let's suppose that
$$dim(V) = \sum_{i = 1}^k dim(W_i) \longrightarrow V = W_1 \oplus W_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus W_k$$
and let's show that this property also holds for $k + 1$.

We have that
$$dim(V) = \sum_{i = 1}^k dim(W_i) + dim(W_{k+1})$$
Let $V' = W_1 + \cdots + W_k$, and we have that
$$dim(V) = dim(V' + W_{k+1}) = dim(V') + dim(W_{k+1}) - dim(V'\cap W_{k+1})$$
Using both expressions, it follows that
$$\sum_{i = 1}^k dim(W_i) = dim(V') - dim(V'\cap W_{k+1})$$

EDIT 1 (in order to leave the proof correct):

Since $dim(V) = dim(V') + dim(W_{k+1}) - dim(V'\cap W_{k+1})$,
$$dim(V) \le dim(V') + dim(W_{k+1})$$
By the other hand, since $dim(V') \le dim(W_1) + \cdots + dim(W_k)$,
$$dim(V') + dim(W_{k+1}) \le dim(V)$$
Thus,
$$dim(V') = \sum_{i = 1}^k dim(W_i), \quad (*)$$
and
$$dim(V'\cap W_{k+1}), \quad (**)$$
By $(*)$, $V = V' \oplus W_{k+1}$ and furthermore, by $(**)$ and the hypothesis of induction
$$V' = \oplus_{i = 1}^k W_i$$
Therefore
$$V = W_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus W_k \oplus W_{k+1}$$

Comment: But you *know* that $\dim W' = \dim W_1 +\dots + \dim W_k$, don't you?

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't know where it follows from.. am I missing some prop?

Comment: Try without induction. Choose a basis for each $W_i$. Can you find a basis of $V$?

Comment: If you had $\dim W' < \sum_{i=1}^k \dim V_i$, then you would have $\dim W \le \dim W' + \dim W_{k+1} < \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\dim V_i$.

Comment: Please use `\dim` instead.

Comment: Oops. Typos in my last comment. $V_i$ should be $W_i$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I was slept, how can I missed that, thanks dear

Comment: @Mark Let $\beta_i$ be a basis for $W_i$ for each $i \in I = \{1, \cdots, k\}$. Since $dim(V) = \sum_{i = 1}^k dim(W_i)$, $dim(V) = \sum_{i = 1}^k |\beta_i|$. By the other hand, since $dim(V) = dim(W_1 + \cdots + W_k)$, $dim(V) = \Big| \bigcup \beta_i \Big|$. Thus, $ \Big| \bigcup \beta_i \Big| = \sum_{i = 1}^k |\beta_i|$ and furthermore, for every $W_i$, holds that $W_i \cap (W_1 + \cdots + W_{i-1} + W_{i+1} + \cdots + W_k) = \{\bar{0}\}$. It follows that $\bigcup \beta_i$ is a basis for $V$. Therefore, $V = W_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus W_k$. Isn't it correct?

Comment: @AnneBauval Yeap! That was the better approach I saw, but still had my doubts. Ted and Mark provided two greater paths for me to understand and solve the proposition! Thanks.